# PyCharm does not recognize iPython when installed via Ubuntu's apt-get

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I've installed `iPython` for Ubuntu's default Python installation (because I couldn't compile some particular program with Anaconda) using `sudo apt-get install ipython`. I can use `/usr/bin/ipython` in the command line.

However, when linked against the default python interpreter in the project settings (/usr/bin/python3.5), the python command line does not support ipython and is the standard python command line.

The project interpreter window also does not list ipython as installed package for the `/usr/bin/python3.5` configuration. But it is there:

```
sudo apt-get install ipython
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ipython is already the newest version (2.4.1-1).
```

How can I fix this?

Output from initializing command line:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /opt/pycharm-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 44543 41206
PyDev console: starting.
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['$$projectPath$$'])
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
```

Comment: when you run ipython from the command line, is it running python2 or python3?

Comment: @GergesDib Ah, it is running python 2..

Comment: So i suppose you'll need pip3 to install ipython, or use an anaconda installation...